# My simple Ada program cannot execute the next command, but during the build and run process it doesn't matter

Tags: ada

sorry I wanted to ask about the Ada language.
First, I want to explain that I first learned the Ada language and me
is trying to make a simple program like the one I attached -> https://pastebin.com/Z1CWUSQv

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
Name : STRING (1..50);

begin
Put("Hallo, whats your name?");
Get(Name);

if (Name = "William") then
   Put_Line ("Hai william");
elsif (Name = "Erick") then
   Put_Line ("Hai erick");
else
   Put_Line ("i dont know, who are you!");
   end if;
end Main;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fTLR.png
So, my questions are:
When I finished writing the code, I did the build and it was a success, after that I did
running the program and the output looks like this:

- Hello, what's your name? (This is ouput)
- Erick (This is my input)

when finished I pressed the Enter key and after that nothing happened
like that the program doesn't execute the next command (I made an if / else command)

I am using the Gnat Studio IDE or online compiler --> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_ada_online.php, so what is the problem with my program? Are there any tools that I need to install and so on?
please know I am very difficult to find references on this issue. I hope all of you reading this can help me.
(Sorry my English is not good)

~ Thank you

Comment: String handling is different to some other languages : you are asking for a 50 character String and not supplying 50 characters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719343/storing-and-using-strings-of-varying-length-ada/61719904#61719904 for one of the alternatives : make the string length exactly right for whatever the user types in.

Comment: You should [install GNAT Studio](https://www.adacore.com/download), it will make things a lot easier to debug. [Learn.adacore.com](https://learn.adacore.com/) is also excellent for the first steps.

Comment: Side note, you don't need to wrap logical expression in brackets. You can write `if x = y then`; for instance `if Name (1 .. Last) = "William" then` in Simon's version.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you who answered my question

Answer (score 9):

Strings are difficult for newcomers to Ada to get right. In this case, the problem is that `Name` is 50 characters long, so

- when you call `Get`, it wants to read 50 characters, and it will carry on reading until it gets 50 characters (or reaches the end of the input). This is why your program appeared to get stuck.
- `"William"` is not 50 characters long, so it cannot possibly be equal to `Name`.

You could use the procedure `Get_Line` ([ARM A.10.7(18)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p18)), something like this:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Name : STRING (1..50);
   Last : Natural;
begin
   Put("Hallo, whats your name?");
   Get_Line (Name, Last);

   if (Name (1 .. Last) = "William") then
      Put_Line ("Hai william");
   elsif (Name (1 .. Last) = "Erick") then
      Put_Line ("Hai erick");
   else
      Put_Line ("i dont know, who are you!");
   end if;
end Main;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, for the answer.
Do you have an ADA language learning module for beginners other than the videos provided by AdaCore on Youtube?

Comment: Look at https://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/, which mentions  https://learn.adacore.com which might suit you